# Python - Append a list with a line from a text file if there's a regex match in the text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to parse through a syslog and append a list with any lines that matches a regex.
Here's an example for a line that I want to append to the list:

```
Jan 31 00:44:34 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (ac)
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
list1 = []

with open("syslog.txt", "r") as log:
  regex = r"ticky:.*ERROR.*"
  for i in log:
    if re.search(regex, str(log)):
      list1.append(i)
```

I have tried the regex on it's own by first adding all the results from i to a string variable and then used the regex on that variable. It was able to find a match so the regex itself is not the issue.

This is for an exercise so this is just the first step and it has to be done using regex because after this step I have to expand on this code to include different types of messages.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems at first glance to me that you are doing `re.search` on the entire log list. I suggest trying:

```py
list1 = []

with open("syslog.txt", "r") as log:
  regex = r"ticky:.*ERROR.*"
  for i in log:
    if re.search(regex, str(i)):
      list1.append(i)
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot lol. That makes so much sense! Can't believe I've been sitting here for 3 hours and didn't see that. Thank you so much!

Comment: You`re welcomed. Don`t worry, we`ve all made this type of mistake at some point haha

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use regex:

```
import re

list1 = []

with open("syslog.txt", "r") as log:
  for i in log:
    if re.findall("ticky:*.ERROR.*", i):
      list1.append(i)
```